# How is the file syscall_32.tbl read/parsed and who does it while building a Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, system-calls

System calls are added to syscall_32.tbl or syscall_64.tbl but how is it being parsed. I never came across a .tbl extension while programming in C.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about x86-related files located at [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls), they are just passed to shell scripts [`syscallhdr.sh`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscallhdr.sh) and [`syscalltbl.sh`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscalltbl.sh) on the same directory, which generate C-headers on the kernel build tree

```
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
```

and

```
arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h
arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_x32.h
arch/x86/include/generated/asm/syscalls_64.h
```

respectively. Those headers are later included/used by appropriate C files.

PS: In general, you may look up such things on the [Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/Makefile)'s.